# Multiple custom invoices creation(self pay and 3rd party payer)

Tags: c#, acumatica

We are doing customization for 3rd party payer invoices creation for one of my Customer.

we have customized a tab-grid(Payer Details) in  Sales screen (SO301000)

we need to create Invoices based on Payer Details tab rows count, on prepare invoice action button click.

I am able to create multiple invoices.

we are facing one challenge:

If item having Allocation(Lot serialnbr) then I am not able to bring qty filed data from SO to Invoice. It is modifying qty as 1, even If we have more than one qty in SOLine.

I stopped base ERP invoice creation, I have implemented a custom code for creating invoices.

I have to override PrepareInvoice method.
  public delegate IEnumerable PrepareInvoiceDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);

Kindly help me on how to implement allocation in this or how to override the creation invoice method.

Please find attached screenshots.

Custom table:TSCustomPayerDetails

Code:

```
public delegate IEnumerable PrepareInvoiceDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
[PXOverride]
public IEnumerable PrepareInvoice(PXAdapter adapter, PrepareInvoiceDelegate baseMethod)
{

    // bool SelfPayer = false;
    SOInvoiceEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOInvoiceEntry>();
    SOOrderEntry ord = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
    SOOrderEntryTSExtension ordext = ord.GetExtension<SOOrderEntryTSExtension>();
    ServiceOrderEntry Sergraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ServiceOrderEntry>();
    ServiceOrderEntryTSExtension SergraphExt = Sergraph.GetExtension<ServiceOrderEntryTSExtension>();
    var row = (SOOrder)Base.Document.Current;
    if (this.SalesPayer != null && this.SalesPayer.Select().Count > 0)
    {
        AccountMaint Accountgraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<AccountMaint>();

        TSCustomPayerDetails SelfBussinessAccountAmount = PXSelect<TSCustomPayerDetails,
           Where<TSCustomPayerDetails.sONbr, Equal<Required<TSCustomPayerDetails.sONbr>>, And<TSCustomPayerDetails.selfPay, IsNotNull>>>.Select(Base, row.OrderNbr);
        #region   Self Payer with 0 invoice
        if (SelfBussinessAccountAmount == null)
        {                   
            var proj = new ARInvoice();
            proj = graph.Document.Insert(proj);
            proj.DocDesc = row.OrderDesc;
            proj.CustomerID = row.CustomerID;
            proj = graph.Document.Update(proj);
            graph.Persist();

            if (Base.Transactions.Select().Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (SOLine arTranBase in Base.Transactions.Select())
                {                          

                    var arTran1 = new ARTran();
                    arTran1 = graph.Transactions.Insert(arTran1);
                    arTran1.RefNbr = graph.Document.Current.RefNbr;
                    arTran1.TranType = "INV";
                    // arTran1.SOOrderType = "IN";
                    // arTran1.TranDesc = "Self Payer Business Account Name" + row.OrderDesc;
                    //if (arTranBase.OrderNbr != null)
                    //    arTran1.SOOrderNbr = arTranBase.OrderNbr;
                    arTran1.UOM = arTranBase.UOM;

                    arTran1.InventoryID = arTranBase.InventoryID;
                    arTran1.LocationID = arTranBase.LocationID;
                    // arTran1.LotSerialNbr = arTranBase.LotSerialNbr;
                    arTran1.SiteID = arTranBase.SiteID;
                    arTran1.TranDesc = arTranBase.TranDesc;
                    arTran1.Qty = arTranBase.OrderQty;
                    // arTran1.CuryUnitPrice = arTranBase.CuryUnitPrice;
                    arTran1.CuryUnitPrice = arTranBase.CuryLineAmt;
                    arTran1.ManualDisc = arTranBase.ManualDisc;
                    //arTran1.SOOrderNbr = arTranBase.OrderNbr;                        

                    //  arTran.UnitPrice = salesPayer.Amount;
                    // arTran.AccountID = salesPayer.Account;


                    arTran1 = graph.Transactions.Update(arTran1);

                    graph.Persist();
                }
            }
            foreach (TSCustomPayerDetails PayerBussinessAccount in PXSelect<TSCustomPayerDetails,
                Where<TSCustomPayerDetails.sONbr, Equal<Required<TSCustomPayerDetails.sONbr>>, And<TSCustomPayerDetails.selfPay, IsNull>>>.Select(Base, row.OrderNbr))
            {
                if (PayerBussinessAccount != null)
                {
                    //var arTran = new ARTran();
                    //arTran = graph.Transactions.Insert(arTran);
                    //arTran.RefNbr = graph.Document.Current.RefNbr;

                    var arTran = new ARTran();
                    ARTran TranItem = PXSelectOrderBy<ARTran,
                    OrderBy<
                        Desc<ARTran.refNbr>>>
                             .SelectWindowed(graph, 0, 1);
                    {
                        graph.Document.Current = PXSelect<ARInvoice, Where<ARInvoice.refNbr, Equal<Required<ARInvoice.refNbr>>>>.Select(Base, TranItem.RefNbr);
                        arTran = graph.Transactions.Insert(arTran);
                        arTran.RefNbr = TranItem.RefNbr;
                    }
                    BAccount Customer = PXSelect<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Required<SOOrder.customerID>>>>.Select(Base, row.CustomerID);
                    if (Customer != null)
                    {
                        if (SelfBussinessAccountAmount != null)
                        {
                            SelfBussinessAccountAmount.Account = Customer.AcctCD;
                            SelfBussinessAccountAmount.AccountName = Customer.AcctName;
                        }
                        // SelfPayerBussinessAccountName = Customer.AcctName;
                        if (PayerBussinessAccount != null)
                            arTran.TranDesc = "Less Payment made by " + PayerBussinessAccount.AccountName;
                    }

                    Account tsAccountID = PXSelect<Account, Where<Account.accountCD, Equal<tsAccount>>>.Select(Accountgraph);
                    if (tsAccountID != null)
                    {
                        arTran.AccountID = tsAccountID.AccountID;
                    }
                    Sub tsSubAccountData = PXSelect<Sub, Where<Sub.subCD, Equal<tsAccount>>>.Select(Accountgraph);
                    if (tsSubAccountData != null)
                    {
                        arTran.SubID = tsSubAccountData.SubID;
                    }
                    arTran.TranType = "INV";
                    // arTran.TranDesc = "Self Payer Business Account Name" + row.OrderDesc;
                    arTran.Qty = 1;
                    if (PayerBussinessAccount != null)
                        // arTran.CuryUnitPrice =  -1 * SelfBussinessAccountAmount.Amount;
                        arTran.CuryUnitPrice = -1 * PayerBussinessAccount.Amount;

                    arTran = graph.Transactions.Update(arTran);
                    graph.Persist();

                    ////    TSCustomPayerDetails PayerBussinessAccount1 = PXSelect<TSCustomPayerDetails,
                    ////Where<TSCustomPayerDetails.sONbr, Equal<Required<TSCustomPayerDetails.sONbr>>, And<TSCustomPayerDetails.selfPay, IsNull>>>.Select(Base, row.OrderNbr);
                    TSCustomPayerDetails customPayer = new TSCustomPayerDetails();
                    customPayer = this.SalesPayer.Insert(customPayer);
                    customPayer.InvoiceNbr = graph.Document.Current.RefNbr;
                    customPayer.SelfPay = true;
                    customPayer.Amount = 0;
                    BAccount Customer1 = PXSelect<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Required<SOOrder.customerID>>>>.Select(Base, row.CustomerID);
                    if (Customer1 != null)
                    {
                        if (customPayer != null)
                        {
                            customPayer.Account = Customer.AcctCD;
                            customPayer.AccountName = Customer.AcctName;
                        }
                    }

                    customPayer = this.SalesPayer.Update(customPayer);
                    Base.Persist();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region   Self Payer invoice
        if (SelfBussinessAccountAmount != null)
        {

            var proj = new ARInvoice();
            proj = graph.Document.Insert(proj);
            proj.DocDesc = row.OrderDesc;
            proj.CustomerID = row.CustomerID;
            proj = graph.Document.Update(proj);
            graph.Persist();

            if (Base.Transactions.Select().Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (SOLine arTranBase in Base.Transactions.Select())
                {

                    var arTran1 = new ARTran();
                    arTran1 = graph.Transactions.Insert(arTran1);
                    arTran1.RefNbr = graph.Document.Current.RefNbr;
                    arTran1.TranType = "INV";
                    // arTran1.SOOrderType = "IN";
                    // arTran1.TranDesc = "Self Payer Business Account Name" + row.OrderDesc;
                    //if (arTranBase.OrderNbr != null)
                    //    arTran1.SOOrderNbr = arTranBase.OrderNbr;
                    arTran1.UOM = arTranBase.UOM;

                    arTran1.InventoryID = arTranBase.InventoryID;
                    arTran1.LocationID = arTranBase.LocationID;
                    // arTran1.LotSerialNbr = arTranBase.LotSerialNbr;
                    arTran1.SiteID = arTranBase.SiteID;
                    arTran1.Qty = arTranBase.OrderQty;
                    arTran1.TranDesc = arTranBase.TranDesc;
                    //arTran1.CuryUnitPrice =  arTranBase.CuryUnitPrice;
                    arTran1.CuryUnitPrice = arTranBase.CuryLineAmt;
                    arTran1.ManualDisc = arTranBase.ManualDisc;
                    //arTran1.SOOrderNbr = arTranBase.OrderNbr;                        

                    //  arTran.UnitPrice = salesPayer.Amount;
                    // arTran.AccountID = salesPayer.Account;
                    arTran1 = graph.Transactions.Update(arTran1);
                    graph.Persist();
                }
            }

            graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOInvoiceEntry>();


            foreach (TSCustomPayerDetails PayerBussinessAccount in PXSelect<TSCustomPayerDetails,
                Where<TSCustomPayerDetails.sONbr, Equal<Required<TSCustomPayerDetails.sONbr>>, And<TSCustomPayerDetails.selfPay, IsNull>>>.Select(Base, row.OrderNbr))
            {
                if (PayerBussinessAccount != null)
                {
                    var arTran = new ARTran();
                    ARTran TranItem = PXSelectOrderBy<ARTran,
                    OrderBy<
                        Desc<ARTran.refNbr>>>
                             .SelectWindowed(graph, 0, 1);
                    {
                        graph.Document.Current = PXSelect<ARInvoice, Where<ARInvoice.refNbr, Equal<Required<ARInvoice.refNbr>>>>.Select(Base, TranItem.RefNbr);
                        arTran = graph.Transactions.Insert(arTran);
                        arTran.RefNbr = TranItem.RefNbr;
                    }
                    BAccount Customer = PXSelect<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Required<SOOrder.customerID>>>>.Select(Base, row.CustomerID);
                    if (Customer != null)
                    {
                        if (SelfBussinessAccountAmount != null)
                        {
                            SelfBussinessAccountAmount.Account = Customer.AcctCD;
                            SelfBussinessAccountAmount.AccountName = Customer.AcctName;
                        }
                        // SelfPayerBussinessAccountName = Customer.AcctName;
                        if (PayerBussinessAccount != null)
                            arTran.TranDesc = "Less Payment made by " + PayerBussinessAccount.AccountName;
                    }
                    // arTran.Qty = 1;
                    Account tsAccountID = PXSelect<Account, Where<Account.accountCD, Equal<tsAccount>>>.Select(Accountgraph);
                    if (tsAccountID != null)
                    {
                        arTran.AccountID = tsAccountID.AccountID;
                    }
                    Sub tsSubAccountData = PXSelect<Sub, Where<Sub.subCD, Equal<tsAccount>>>.Select(Accountgraph);
                    if (tsSubAccountData != null)
                    {
                        arTran.SubID = tsSubAccountData.SubID;
                    }
                    arTran.TranType = "INV";
                    // arTran.TranDesc = "Self Payer Business Account Name" + row.OrderDesc;
                    arTran.Qty = 1;
                    if (PayerBussinessAccount != null)
                        // arTran.CuryUnitPrice =  -1 * SelfBussinessAccountAmount.Amount;
                        arTran.CuryUnitPrice = -1 * PayerBussinessAccount.Amount;

                    arTran = graph.Transactions.Update(arTran);
                    graph.Persist();

                    //    TSCustomPayerDetails PayerBussinessAccount1 = PXSelect<TSCustomPayerDetails,
                    //Where<TSCustomPayerDetails.sONbr, Equal<Required<TSCustomPayerDetails.sONbr>>, And<TSCustomPayerDetails.selfPay, IsNull>>>.Select(Base, row.OrderNbr);
                    SelfBussinessAccountAmount.InvoiceNbr = graph.Document.Current.RefNbr;
                    SalesPayer.Update(SelfBussinessAccountAmount);
                    Base.Persist();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region   3rdparty payer invoice
        foreach (TSCustomPayerDetails PartyPayerBussinessAccount in PXSelect<TSCustomPayerDetails,
           Where<TSCustomPayerDetails.sONbr, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>, And<TSCustomPayerDetails.selfPay, IsNull>>>.Select(Sergraph, row.OrderNbr))
        {
            if (PartyPayerBussinessAccount != null)
            {
                var proj1 = new ARInvoice();
                proj1 = graph.Document.Insert(proj1);
                proj1.DocDesc = row.OrderDesc;
                // proj1.CustomerID = row.CustomerID;

                BAccount PayerContact = PXSelect<BAccount, Where<BAccount.acctCD, Equal<Required<BAccount.acctCD>>>>.Select(Base, PartyPayerBussinessAccount.Account);
                if (PayerContact != null)
                {
                    proj1.CustomerID = PayerContact.BAccountID;
                    // proj1.BillContactID = PayerContact.BAccountID;
                    //arContact.ContactID = PayerContact.BAccountID;
                    //graph.Billing_Contact.Update(arContact);
                    //graph.Actions.PressSave();
                }

                proj1 = graph.Document.Update(proj1);
                graph.Persist();

                var arTran = new ARTran();
                arTran = graph.Transactions.Insert(arTran);
                arTran.RefNbr = graph.Document.Current.RefNbr;
                // arTran.SOOrderNbr = PartyPayerBussinessAccount.SONbr;

                // string SelfPayerBussinessAccountName1 = string.Empty;
                BAccount Customer = PXSelect<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Required<SOOrder.customerID>>>>.Select(Base, row.CustomerID);
                if (Customer != null)
                {
                    // SelfPayerBussinessAccountName1 = Customer.AcctName;

                    // arTran.TranDesc = SelfPayerBussinessAccountName1 + "," + row.OrderDesc;
                    if (PartyPayerBussinessAccount != null)
                    {
                        if (row.OrderDesc != null)
                            arTran.TranDesc = PartyPayerBussinessAccount.AccountName + " , " + row.OrderDesc;
                        else
                            arTran.TranDesc = PartyPayerBussinessAccount.AccountName;
                    }
                    //PartyPayerBussinessAccount.Account = Customer.AcctCD;
                    //PartyPayerBussinessAccount.AccountName = Customer.AcctName;
                }

                //if (PartyPayerBussinessAccount != null)
                //{
                //    arTran.TranDesc = PartyPayerBussinessAccount + " " + row.OrderDesc;
                //}
                arTran.Qty = 1;

                Account tsAccountID = PXSelect<Account, Where<Account.accountCD, Equal<tsAccount>>>.Select(Accountgraph);
                if (tsAccountID != null)
                {
                    arTran.AccountID = tsAccountID.AccountID;
                }
                Sub tsSubAccountData = PXSelect<Sub, Where<Sub.subCD, Equal<tsAccount>>>.Select(Accountgraph);
                if (tsSubAccountData != null)
                {
                    arTran.SubID = tsSubAccountData.SubID;
                }
                // arTran.CuryUnitPrice = PartyPayerBussinessAccount.Amount;
                if (PartyPayerBussinessAccount != null)
                    arTran.CuryUnitPrice = PartyPayerBussinessAccount.Amount;
                arTran.TaxCategoryID = "EXEMPT";
                arTran = graph.Transactions.Update(arTran);
                graph.Persist();

                // TSCustomPayerDetails PartyPayerBussinessAccount1 = PXSelect<TSCustomPayerDetails,
                //Where<TSCustomPayerDetails.sONbr, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>, And<TSCustomPayerDetails.selfPay, IsNull>>>.Select(Base, row.OrderNbr);

                PartyPayerBussinessAccount.InvoiceNbr = graph.Document.Current.RefNbr;

                SergraphExt.ServicePayer.Update(PartyPayerBussinessAccount);
                Sergraph.Actions.PressSave();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        SOInvoiceEntry ie = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOInvoiceEntry>();
        ie.Document.Current = ie.Document.Search<ARInvoice.docType, ARInvoice.refNbr>(((ARInvoice)graph.Document.Current).DocType, ((ARInvoice)graph.Document.Current).RefNbr, ((ARInvoice)graph.Document.Current).DocType);
        throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(ie, "Invoice");
    }
    else
    {
        baseMethod(adapter);
    }
    return adapter.Get();
}
```

Kindly help me in this where I am going wrong or how to handle this scansion.

Comment: >300 lines of code is not a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have completed this. Thanks.